# Fix Fatal Error Condition showing system path Magento get.php

Tags: apache-2.2, security

I've noticed there are a large number of servers running Magento Commerce that will return a fatal error showing the system path:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File '/usr/local/www/magento/data1702/media/css' does not exists.' in /usr/local/www/magento/data1702/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/www/magento/data1702/get.php(205): Varien_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http->send('/usr/local/www/...') #1 /usr/local/www/magento/data1702/get.php(165): sendFile('/usr/local/www/...') #2 {main} thrown in /usr/local/www/magento/data1702/lib/Varien/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php on line 96
```

Magento as an application is generally good about supressing error messages. How can a linux server running apache be configured to avoid returning this error message since the app has problems suppressing it.

Answer (score 1):

actually, this is a php error.

You can edit your php.ini file to disable php error display by setting  display_errors to 0 instead of 1

Comment: The php.ini file on the server has display_errors set to "off", but still displays the error. The index.php file has this line: #ini_set('display_errors', 1); . Would that turn it back on?

Comment: What does the # do?

Comment: the # is a one-line shell-style comment, meaning that then content after the # within the same line is not exectuted.
are you sure you checked the right php.ini file, can you check with a script containing a phpinfo()  call ?

Comment: This is the output: display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off . I believe this is the reason so many servers will return the errors. Most people know to turn display_errors to off in production.

Comment: +1 because it was a display_errors issue. It is being set to "on" in get.php inside the application. I'd still like to know how this can be prevented at the server level outside the application if possible.

Comment: You have two options

- turn on safe_mode into your php.ini : this may be too agressive and disable some functions your app needs

- add ini_set to the list of disable_functions of your php.ini